# How can I italicise a certain word (which occurs multiple times) in my string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text that reads "Hello world. The world is so beautiful." I want to change it to "Hello *world*. The *world* is so beautiful."

I tried the following code but it only changes the first word.

```
 let string : NSString =  "Hello world. The world is so beautiful."
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string! as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
 let italicFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]
 attributedString.addAttributes(italicFontAttribute, range: (string!.range(of: "world")))
```

Comment: Post the code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: OMG are you seen this `world. World`, both world are case senstive,

Comment: if both `world` are small case  then my answer s works

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for pointing it out . I have updated the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution added to the others, but which makes a search for the specific term and replaces all of the occurrences, could help you creating a general method for this:

```
var sampleString : String = "Hello world. The world is so beautiful."
let searchTerm : String = "world"

var searchRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, sampleString.characters.count)
var positionRange : NSRange = ((sampleString as NSString).substring(with: searchRange) as NSString).range(of: searchTerm)
var actualRange : NSRange = positionRange

var attributedString : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sampleString)

while (positionRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    // Update attributed string
    actualRange.location = searchRange.location + positionRange.location
    attributedString.addAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Italic", size: CGFloat(22)) ], range: actualRange)

    // Proceed to the next position
    searchRange.location += positionRange.location + searchTerm.characters.count
    searchRange.length = sampleString.characters.count - searchRange.location

    positionRange = ((sampleString as NSString).substring(with: searchRange) as NSString).range(of: searchTerm)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
attributedString.addAttributes(italicFontAttribute, range: (string!.range(of: "world")))
attributedString.addAttributes(italicFontAttribute, range: (string!.range(of: "World")))
```

try this capital and small Charter both find in string.